# ReportPayment() method in main is giving errors

Tags: java

I'm asked to do the following tasks:

- Five private variables to store the Name, Surname, Gender, age,
  AmountPayout
- Include an Object Instantiation that has two methods called. The one methods is called Info(), this will use a GUI to retrieve Name,
  Surname, Gender, age, AmountPayout
- Create another method called ReportPayment(), this will use a GUI to display the information of the user. Within this methods create
  another method called PaymentCalculator that parse a parameter of the
  amount to be paid.
- Use the amount to deduct 15% tax, and return the final amount to be displayed.

My code returns:

> required string string int double

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Details det = new Details();
    det.info();
    det. ReportPayment();
}

class Details
{

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String gender;
    private int age , age1;
    private double  AmountPayout , SubPayout;

    void info() 
    {
        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter the Patient Name :");

        String surname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter the Patient Surname :");

        String age = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter the age of the patient :");
        int age1 = Integer.parseInt(age);

        String gender = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter the Patient gender :");

        String AmountPayout = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter the Patient payout :");
        double SubPayout = Double.parseDouble(AmountPayout);
    }

    void ReportPayment(String name, String surname, int age, double AmountPayout) 
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Victim of Listeriosis" + "\n"
                + "Patient Name:" + name + "" + surname + "\n"
                + "Age:" + age + "\n"
                + "Payout:" + AmountPayout);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice homework. What's the question?

Comment: haha , det. ReportPayment(); is giving me an error , required string string int double

Comment: have you tryed to put the required string, int and double?

Comment: in the method in main ? if so yes

Comment: your previous comment explicitly states you haven't. And the code in your post show that you haven't.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Reworked the answer:
I tried to run the code myself and with a little tweaking it works perfectly fine. We are getting there. I think thi is the whole thing you should need!

This should now fix your error aswell as fit the requirements you have.

I changed:

- renamed ReportPayment() to reportPayment()
- removed te space inbetween
  "det." and "ReportPayment() in the main class
- Rewrote your attributes
- rewrote the info() method
- added the calculation for taxes as required

Main.java

```
public class Main {
    private static boolean running = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Details det = new Details();
        det.info();
        det.reportPayment();
    }

}
```

Details.java

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class Details {
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private int age;
    private String gender;
    private double AmountPayout;

    void info() {
        this.name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the Patient Name :");
        this.surname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the Patient Surname :");
        String rawAge = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the age of the patient :");
        this.age = Integer.parseInt(rawAge);
        this.gender = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the Patient gender :");
        String rawPayout = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the Patient payout :");
        this.AmountPayout = Double.parseDouble(rawPayout);


    }

    void reportPayment() {
        paymentCalculator();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Victim of Listeriosis" + "\n" + "Patient Name:" + name + " " + surname
                + "\n" + "Age:" + age + "\n" + "Payout:" + AmountPayout);

    }

    private void paymentCalculator() {
        this.AmountPayout = this.AmountPayout * 0.85;
    }
}
```

Comment: Code will work perfectly even with space between, he can write `det . ReportPayment()` and it still works.

Comment: You should explain why it didn't work and what you did to fix it

Comment: added the changes I made. Why the downvote? having a bad day?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Comment: the null , null , 0 , 0 doesn't display information in output

Comment: this should now fix the problems you had aswell as comply with the requirements you have.

Comment: @Tobias Götz But i need the info() method to be in as stated in the question above

Comment: yeah, i redid the whole thing again, if you refresh it you should see it. now also added the tax calculation thingy.

Comment: You are so helpful ! Cant thank you enough , the payment calculator doesn't deduct the 15%:(

Comment: How come? For me it does. Are you running exactly the code I posted?

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help ;)

Comment: unfortunately i cant ask another question that i wanted you to help me with :(

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should remove c# from tags, this has nothing to do with it.

Then take look at your ReportPayment method, as you can see in method signature you have 4 parameters that you must past once you call method.

So instead of writing  `det.ReportPayment();`
You should write `det.ReportPayment("name","surname", 10, 30);` to make it work

But that isn't what you really want, because you are supposed to use class attributes you don't need to pass them to method, so you should change method to something like this:

```
// Note that we don't have parameters anymore
void reportPayment() { 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Victim of Listeriosis" + "\n"
            + "Patient Name:" + name + "" + surname + "\n"
            + "Age:" + age + "\n"
            + "Payout:" + AmountPayout);
}
```

Last issue with your code is that you are not following conventions, this doesn't affect how your code works but it affects other people reading your code, whenever using some language make sure to get familiar with standard conventions in other to make code more understandable for other developers that will look at it.

In Java standard for naming is [Camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) notation, with difference between class names and variable/method names being that classes always start with **UPPERCASE** letter while variable and method names start with **lowercase**.

Class name - `StringBuilder`
Method name - `reportPayment`
Variabl name - `amountPayout`

Another convention in Java is that `{` bracket comes just after method signature not on next line.

Finally in other to learn more about above mentioned things and many others I suggest you to buy/borrow some good Java introduction book, there are many out there.

Comment: Thank you , will definitely have a look at naming conventions and so on , new to java

Comment: doing this runs but gives me a null as output

Comment: Inside your info method don't create new variables, assign those values to class attributes, for example `this.name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter the Patient Name :");`

Answer (score 0):

2 issues with your code:

**First issue:** you forget the parameters in the call to `det.reportPayment();` (note the lowercase `r`).
I assume you want to use the attributes stored in `Details`.

You have two options:

- Pass the attributes as parameters:

  ```
  det. ReportPayment(det.name, det.surname, det.age, det.AmountPayout);
  ```

  Note this will not works without more modification as those attributes are privates. You have to either make them public or add getters (and then replace `det.name` with `det.getName()`, etc.)
- Remove the parameters and use the Detail attribute directly in the method as the method is in the same class (best solution).

  ```
  void reportPayment() {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Victim of Listeriosis" + "\n" + "Patient Name:" + this.name + "" + this.surname
          + "\n" + "Age:" + this.age + "\n" + "Payout:" + this.AmountPayout);
  }
  ```

**Second issue:** you never set your class attribute.

In `info()`method, you ask the user to give values. Those values are stored in temporary variables but not in the class attributes.
For example, push the values in `this.name` instead of creating a new `String name`.

```
    this.name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the Patient Name :");
    this.surname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the Patient Surname :");
```

and so on.

Unrelated: have a look at [java naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Answer (score 0):

- Adding "this" in the info() method made the name , surname and gender work but the age and AmountPayout still returns a null

  public static void main(String[] args) {

  ```
  Details det = new Details();
  det.info();
  det.reportPayment();
  ```

  }

} 
class Details {

```
private String name;
private String surname;
private String gender;
private int age , age1;
private double  AmountPayout , SubPayout;

void info() 
{
  this.name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter the Patient Name :");

  this.surname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter the Patient Surname :");

  String age = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter the age of the patient :");
  int age1 = Integer.parseInt(age);

  this.gender = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter the Patient gender :");

  String AmountPayout = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter the Patient payout :");
  double SubPayout = Double.parseDouble(AmountPayout);
}
```